# PIDinRootline doesn't work as expected

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x

I'm new in typoscript and I'm just playing with some test.
What I'm trying to do is change the value of a MARK in HTML template, depending on which part of the site I am.
I'll try using the conditions `PIDinRootline` but it doesn't work.

Here my typoscript snippet:

```
page.100 = TEXT

[PIDinRootline = 48]
page.100.value = IS son of uID 48
page.10.marks {
BANNERIMG = TEXT
BANNERIMG.value = something
}
[ELSE]
page.100.value = IS not son of uID 48
page.10.marks {
BANNERIMG = TEXT
BANNERIMG.value = something but not a SON
}
[END]
page.100.stdWrap.wrap = <strong>|</strong>

page.110 = TEXT
page.110.data = debug:rootLine
page.110.stdWrap.wrap = <strong>|</strong>
```

and this is a screen of the output page:

[image]

there is some error in the code or I misunderstood the sense of the condition `PIDinRootline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a direct contact in the Italian mailing list, the problem was caused by a wrong use of templates.
In the subpage there was a template with the "Clear Constant", "Clear setup" and "is Root Level" checkboxes active.
Unchecking them, everything works correctly.